# Any ideas why I get a 'Data Type Mismatch' error in this Sql String?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am using Visual Basic Express 2010 and am using an Access Database

`Dim count as Integer`

`SQL = "SELECT * FROM transac WHERE transac_id = " & "'" & count & "'"`

Comment: can you please post the sql query correctly?

Comment: Paging Bobby Tables, please pick up the white courtesy phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume your `transac_id` is an `INT` datatype, and you are placing single quotes around the `count` making it a string.

Try:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM transac WHERE transac_id = " & count
```

Comment: Just a note, dynamic SQL can be a large security issue. You should parameterize the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

```
"select * from transac where transac_id = " & count;
```